# Is it possible to "zoom in" in Windows (Vista), like we can in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-vista, zoom

One of the features of Ubuntu that I miss in Windows is the [**zoom in** feature](http://newtoubuntu.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/zoom-in/).

Does someone know how can that be achieved in Windows?

***PS:*** I am **not** looking for the zoom that Vista provides by default [[1](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Quick-Zoom-on-the-Windows-Vista-Desktop-and-In-Explorer-36646.shtml) [2](http://www.vistaclues.com/zoom-in-to-text-files-pictures-and-your-desktop/)] because it is application specific. It zooms selectively. For example - if I Ctrl+scroll on desktop, icons get zoomed - not the wallpaper, if I do that in IE, the page gets zoomed [but not the Navigation bar or the taskbar].

I want **everything** to get zoomed.

If you have used the **Desktop zoom** of **Ubuntu**, you will understand.

Also please do **not** suggest Windows magnifier. It sucks.

Comment: Win7 has this feature, which is lovely.

Comment: really?? I am stuck with Vista :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout this tool:

[ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx)

It's very popular and works well for presentations, so it should probably suit what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks. Zoomit is cool. just messes up the resolution though while zooming in.